# wpdb prepare sql problem

Tags: sql, wpdb

I have problem with wpdb prepare and sql query. If i run the query directly thru wpdb->get_results it's working fine. Here it is:

```
$alabala_sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts p 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr 
      ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt 
      ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id 
    inner join  $wpdb->terms t 
      on t.term_id=tt.term_id and t.slug='$curPageId'
    WHERE 
      p.post_title LIKE '$getChar%'        
      AND p.post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii' 
      AND p.post_status = 'publish';
    "
);
/*Make sql query to take posts*/
$eventsPosts = $wpdb->get_results($alabala_sql);
```

But it doesn't work.
Also i tried that way:

```
$alabala_sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts p 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr 
      ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt 
      ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id 
    inner join  $wpdb->terms t 
      on t.term_id=tt.term_id and t.slug=$s
    WHERE 
      p.post_title LIKE $s%        
      AND p.post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii' 
      AND p.post_status = 'publish';
    ", $curPageId, $getChar
);
/*Make sql query to take posts*/
$eventsPosts = $wpdb->get_results($alabala_sql);
```

But again it didn't worked. Please tell me where is my mistake ? Both vars are strings.
Regards.

Comment: `slug=$s` must be `slug=%s` and `LIKE $s%` must be `LIKE %s`.

Comment: That way:`SELECT * 
  FROM $wpdb->posts p 
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr 
    ON p.ID = tr.object_id
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt 
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id 
  inner join  $wpdb->terms t 
    on t.term_id=tt.term_id and t.slug=%s
  WHERE 
    p.post_title LIKE %s%        
    AND p.post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii' 
    AND p.post_status = 'publish';
        ", $curPageId, $getChar` Didn't work.

Comment: Of course it didn’t. Lookup how [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) works. You cannot use a plain `%` in a string evaluated by `sprintf`. Use `$getChar . '%'` instead.

Comment: Well. I'm not sure i get it but like this: `SELECT * 
  FROM $wpdb->posts p 
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr 
    ON p.ID = tr.object_id
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt 
    ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id 
  inner join  $wpdb->terms t 
    on t.term_id=tt.term_id and t.slug=$curPageId
  WHERE 
    p.post_title LIKE $getChar. '%'        
    AND p.post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii' 
    AND p.post_status = 'publish';
        ",$curPageId, $getChar` It doesnt worked again.

Comment: Again: you cannot use a plain `%` in that string.

Comment: You can use `%%` for a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `%` character into your SQL string without confusing `sprintf()` add it to the *replacement* string:

```
$alabala_sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->posts p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr
        ON p.ID = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt
        ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN  $wpdb->terms t
        ON t.term_id=tt.term_id and t.slug= %s
    WHERE
        p.post_title LIKE %s
        AND p.post_type = 'filmi-i-serialii'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish';
    ", 
    $curPageId, 
    $getChar . '%'
);           /* ^ like this */
```

Comment: Or use `%%` to get a literal.

Comment: @t31os `prepare()` add quotes around the value, so the result would be `'value'%`.

Comment: Actually, prepare doesn't quote the value when you use a literal. So `LIKE '%%%s'` would work just fine. It would be a little confusing to read that back to yourself later though(and you might easily forget why that one instance is written that way).